# c++17 compatible std::bind_front alternative

Tags: c++, performance, functional-programming, reinventing-the-wheel, template-meta-programming

One of the things that has been really exciting me in c++20 is `std::bind_front`. Using placeholders with `std::bind` and `boost::bind` has really bothered me and the code looked messier and messier with each call to bind. It was bad enough for me to decide to enable `-std=c++2a` and pray that I wouldn't have to fix the code in the future if something gets changed.

I was messing around with parameter pack recursion when I realized I could make a `std::bind_front` alternative that would work in c++17. If I removed the `std::invoke` it would even work in c++11.

It even seems to compile faster than my standard library's implementation.

---

```
//#include <utility>
//#include <functional>

//of course this would go into some kind of namespace

template <class F, class A>
struct _bind_obj {
    F originalFunc;
    A arg;
    template <class... Args>
    inline auto operator()(Args&&... a){
        return std::invoke(originalFunc, arg, std::forward<Args>(a)...);
    }
    _bind_obj(F &&_originalFunc, A &&_arg) :
        originalFunc(std::forward<F>(_originalFunc)),
        arg(std::forward<A>(_arg)){

    }
};

template <class F, class A>
auto bind_front(F &&func, A &&arg){
    return _bind_obj<F, A>(
        std::forward<F>(func),
        std::forward<A>(arg)
    );
}

template <class F, class FirstA, class... A>
auto bind_front(F &&func, FirstA &&firstA, A&&... a){
    return bind_front(
        bind_front(
            std::forward<F>(func),
            std::forward<FirstA>(firstA)
        ),
        std::forward<A>(a)...
    );
}
```

---

So what do you think? Are there some cases in `std::bind_front` that I missed? Are there any optimizations I should make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bind_front` can (and should) be made `constexpr`.

The callable object and the bound arguments need to be decayed per the standard.

You can store all arguments in a tuple instead of generating nested wrappers:

```
template <class FD, class... Args>
class bind_obj {
    // ...
    FD func;
    std::tuple<Args...> args;
};
```

and then call

```
std::apply(func, args, std::forward<A>(call_args)...)
```

(which internally calls `invoke`.)

Otherwise, nice code.

Comment: Thanks! I see an improvement in compile time and executable size with constexpr. Out of curiosity, what are the advantages of using `std::apply` and tuples over nested wrappers?

Comment: @user233009 You are welcome.  With nested wrappers, the compiler has to instantiate the template multiple times (`n` instantiations of `bind_obj` for `n` args) and there are multiple function calls (think of `f1(f2(f3(f4(f5, a5), a4), a3), a2), a1)` ...  scary)  whereas `std::apply` simply expands the template parameter pack, resulting a single function call (`f(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)`).  That should explain the reduction in both compile time and executable size.

Answer (score 8):

> Are there some cases in `std::bind_front` that I missed?

There are several significant differences between `std::bind_front`'s behavior and your implementations.

---

First, your implementation unconditionally returns a value. But what if the callable in question returned a reference? The behavior is just incorrect.

---

Second, `std::bind_front` is SFINAE-friendly but yours is not. That is, I can check to see if I can invoke the result with a certain set of arguments. Here is a silly example demonstrating this:

```
auto f = [](int i, int j) { return i + j; };
auto g = std::bind_front(f, 1);
auto g2 = your::bind_front(f, 1);

// this is ok, static assertion doesn't trigger
static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<decltype(g), int, int>);

// this is a compile error
static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<decltype(g2), int, int>);
```

Basically, asking the question "Can I call you with two `int`s?" leads to an instantiation failure outside of the immediate context, and will always be a hard error.

You can fix this and the reference issue described above by specified the correct return type instead of `auto`:

```
template <class... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<F&, A, Args...> operator()(Args&&... a) { ... }
```

---

Third, you're capturing your arguments differently. Consider:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
auto f = [](std::string const& s, int i) { return s[i]; }

auto g = std::bind_front(f, s);
auto g2 = your::bind_front(f, s);
s = "Goodbye";

assert(g(0) == 'H'); // ok
assert(g2(0) == 'H'); // fails
```

`std::bind_front` owns everything. You keep references to all the lvalues. The way the standard library works is if you want to capture by reference, you use `std::ref`.

Basically, this:

```
template <class F, class A>
auto bind_front(F &&func, A &&arg){
    return _bind_obj<F, A>(
        std::forward<F>(func),
        std::forward<A>(arg)
    );
}
```

should be:

```
template <class F, class A>
auto bind_front(F &&func, A &&arg){
    return _bind_obj<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<A>>(
        std::forward<F>(func),
        std::forward<A>(arg)
    );
}
```

---

Fourth, your result is *only* invocable on a non-`const` object. But if the callable I'm `bind_front()`-ing has a `const` `operator()`, I should be able to invoke it as `const` too right?

The same can be said for ref-qualifiers: if I have a function object with `&`- and `&&-`qualified overloads, `bind_front` should respect that.

The solution is actually to write four overloads of `operator()`:

```
template <class... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<F&, A, Args...> operator()(Args&&... a) &;

template <class... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<F const&, A, Args...> operator()(Args&&... a) const&;

template <class... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<F, A, Args...> operator()(Args&&... a) &&;

template <class... Args>
inline std::invoke_result_t<F const, A, Args...> operator()(Args&&... a) const &&;
```

Note that I'm also adjusting the type of `F` in the type trait, and be sure to move the callable in the rvalue cases.